# How can I compare ArrayList of integer 2D array with int in java

Tags: java, arraylist, int

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Mutation {
public Mutation()
{

}
private ArrayList<int[][]> allWords=new ArrayList<int[][]>();






public ArrayList<int[][]> wordGenrator(int noOfWords)
{
    int rand,j;
    int word[][]=new int[8][8];
    for(int i=0;i<noOfWords;i++)
    {   
        for(j=0;j<8;j++)
        {
            rand = new Random().nextInt(2);
            System.out.print(rand);
            word[i][j]=rand;
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        allWords.add(word);
    }
    return allWords;
}    
public boolean isExistWordOfAllOnes() 
{
    int counter;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        counter=0;
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
        {
            if(equals(this.allWords.get(i)[i][j]==1)
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        if(counter==8)
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;       
}
```

The loop is running well, but this is not comparing correctly. I want to do if    `allword(i)` have all 1's then return true otherwise false. 
Now this is my whole code of same class.. I'm calling these functions in another main class...

Comment: What in tarnation are you actually ***doing*** in that loop?  I have no idea where half of those symbols or numbers came from.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: all numbers generating randomly... in other function of same class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with 2D array initialization

What will be value of 2D array if `noOfWords=1`?

```
int word[][]=new int[8][8];
for(int i=0;i<noOfWords;i++)
{   
    for(j=0;j<8;j++)
    {
        rand = new Random().nextInt(2);
        System.out.print(rand);
        word[i][j]=rand;
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    allWords.add(word);
}
```

Look at the inline comments.

```
public boolean isExistWordOfAllOnes() 
{
    int counter;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) // iterate all the words that are 2D arrays
    {
        counter=0;
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++) // row
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++) { // column
                if (this.allWords.get(i)[j][k]==1) { // if it is equal to 1
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        if(counter==8*8)//total 64 ones in 8*8 2D array
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;       
}
```

Comment: then **if** returns  always true .

Answer (score 0):

As far as I read your code and your text I think you have a int[5][8] Array and you'd like to check whether there is at least one "1" in every row of the array or not. In that case you juse need to change the the Code as followed

```
public boolean isExistWordOfAllOnes() 
{
    int counter;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        counter=0;
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
        {
            if(this.allWords.get(i)[i][j]==1)
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        if(counter < 1)   // If there were no 1's then count should still be 0
        {                 // and the method returns false as a row was found  
            return false; // in which there wasn't a 1
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That ; should be a )

> if(equals(this.allWords.get(i)[i][j]==1);

Also, the == is already comparing two things, thus the "equals" is not. Get rid of the equals.
This should be outside the for:

> allWords.add(word);

With that change, there will only be one word[][], thus, change the i for a 1:

> this.allWords.get(1)...